# Statuses - Which data type to use?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently looking at the code I've produced and I'm trying to improve its readability and quality. Here's an example of how I'd approach a simple problem, which I've always felt was a poor solution.

Users table with the below "statuses", or elevation levels in this example

1. Employee
2. Supervisor
3. Admin

(these could be anything, for example, a project could have an "incomplete", "on hold" and "complete" status)

In the past, I've always stored this as an INT value then when printing out the accounts and their statuses, I will write a function to convert this back to text, to be printed on a page e.g.

`if userLevel === 3 { return "Admin"; };`

This has always felt like a bad solution, and it's not very flexible. The addition of any new types of account would require the function to be updated. This format also makes it very difficult to read page restrictions.

If I were to add the line:

`if userLevel !== 2 OR 3 { // Redirect to error page };`

You can see how this could become confusing down the line.

Recently I've started storing these "statuses" as a string purely so it's more readable. But now I've been getting more into Laravel, I wonder if I should have additional database tables devoted solely to this.

So my question - what is the appropriate data type for this kind of data, and what would be the ideal way to interact with it?

Comment: Is it a string? Return type is a string. Is it an int? return type is an int. etc. etc. etc. etc..... The content of the string, value of the int, count of the array, etc, etc. has no bearing on the definition of the type, it is what it is.

Comment: Why do you convert a int to a text in de code while having it already in the database?

Comment: @RaymondNijland There is no logical reason, this is just the way I was taught, which I am beginning to question. As I mention in the post, it has never felt right that I should be converting the type.

Comment: Have two more tables. One will contain the Roles, one to attach a user to a role, namely UserRole. Much more dynamic I think and more granular control.

Comment: Constants are a good way to handle this; plus they are basically the way PHP itself handles stuff like this in a lot of places already (think error reporting `E_ALL` for example.) _“when printing out the accounts and their statuses, I will write a function to convert this back to text”_ - nothing wrong with that IMHO, plus you would not want this hard-coded with the actual text anyway, if for example adding a second language to the website might be an option in the future. Avoid such direct correlation between your application logic and your UI.

Answer (score 0):

In legacy code I would use constants and basically bit doesn't really matter what kind of data is in it. It is readable, you can easily find usages and your IDE can help you out.

In new code where you have a lot of business logic, you can create a create a small class representing the status so you can put the logic there.

In DB - you can find couple of articles saying that enum is not a good idea. If you want to optimize a lot, tinyint can help you, but using a short string is good as well (I normally use it). Then you should translate it in a php ofc , I recommend the object approach described above.

Answer (score 0):

this may or maynot fit your particular application but I have often found bitwise operations convenient for having `0 or more` attributes in a single integer.

e.g. let's say you assign the following:

```
$admin = 0b1; //(1)
$employee = 0b10; //(2)
$supervisor = 0b100; //(4)
```

now you want to assign an integer value for `$status` that is a bitwise `or` of appropriate values.

so, a supervisor is both `employee` and `supervisor` so they would have an integer value of

`2|4 = 0b010 | 0b100 = 0b110 = 6`.

now when you want to see if user has a `status`, just mask something like:

```
if(($statusInt & $supervisor) != 0){
    // it is a supervisor...  //maybe more, at least supervisor
}
```

you can of course have many more `statuses` in a single integer, or INT database column, this way.